# Passing Data between View Controllers : from uitableview to a details view controller

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uistoryboard

I am using IOS 5 and Storyboard coding. I have built an application in which i have a tableView connected to a sqlite database with a search bar.
When we touch a row, it will take us automatically to another view controller called "Details".
I need to pass data from my table view to the details view controller, pass for example the author.title to the labelText.text field.
Any ideas?

Edited question:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
//    NSString *Title;
    Details *dv = (Details*)segue.destinationViewController;
    author.title = dv.labelText.text;
}
```

Partial code:

```
//
//  Details.m
//  AuthorsApp
//
//  Created by georges ouyoun on 7/17/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "Details.h"
#import "Author.h"


@interface Details ()

@end

@implementation Details

@synthesize labelText;
@synthesize selectedAuthors;
@synthesize author;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
   self.labelText.text = self.author.title;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSLog(@"Everything is ok now !");
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
  //  [self setLabelText:nil];
    NSLog(@"U have entered view did unload");
    [super viewDidUnload];

    [self setLabelText:Nil];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
//    NSString *Title;
    Details *dv = (Details*)segue.destinationViewController;
  //  author.title = dv.labelText.text;
    dv.labelText.text = author.title;
}




/*
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"AuthorsCell"]) {

        [segue.destinationViewController setLabelText:author.title];

    }


}




/*
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{ 

    self.labelText.text = author.title;

    NSLog(@"U have entered the viewWillAppear tag");
  //  detailsLabel.text = food.description;
}
*/

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [labelText release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For demo purpose, I will assume we have two view controllers `ListViewController` and `DetailViewController`. ListViewController has tableview and you have created a `segue between your tableview cell and details view controller`.

I'm assuming you are naming it as 'DetailSegue'. Your storyboard should look similar to the below image.

[image]

Select the segue between tableViewCell and DetailViewController, open the attributes inspector and specify the identifier as 'DetailSegue'. See the image below,

[image]

Run the application now, you should see a smooth navigation from ListViewController to DetailViewController.

`Assuming you datasource is an array of stings and you have your datasource and delegate setup already properly for your list tableView`.

Add a method prepareForSegue:sender in your List view controller, this method will get called whenever segue is about to execute.This method will be automatically invoked.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"DetailSegue"]) {
    DetailViewController *detailVC = (DetailViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)sender];
    detailVC.title = [self.source objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  }
}
```

Add a property called `title` in DetailViewController to store the selected title and add another outlet for UILabel to display the title in the view.

DetailViewController.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface RecipeListViewController : NSObject

@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *title;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;

@end
```

---

DetailViewController.m

```
@implementation RecipeListViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.titleLabel.text = self.title;
}
@end
```

Don't forget to connect the outlet. I hope this gives you an rough idea of how we can pass data between view controllers.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer..although i have changed the whole hierarchy since the time i posted this question, but your demonstration could help out someone in the future...thank you and your 100% right

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to use the

`- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender`

method (override) witch allows you to pass details by getting the segue.destinationViewController, then set the attributes of the destination controller.

e.g

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
detailViewController *dv = (detailViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
dv.attribute1 = dataFromTable;
}
```

If, for example you have your tables data in the array an easy way to do this is to get the row number of the row pushed and set it to a variable

```
int rowPressed;

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

rowPressed = indexPath.row;

}
```

Then in the `PrepareForSegue` pass the data to the DetailViewController. Using the rowPressed to get the relevant data from your data model.

Hope this helps!

Comment: could you please provide a code snippet explaining this matter? thank you in advance

Comment: Am i doing anything wrong ? :


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    labelText.text = author.title;

}

Comment: @EliasRahme I added more detail to my answer check, it out and let me know if your still stuck.

Comment: I am pretty lost, i am really new to Xcode , could you please check my edited question to make sure whether i am on the right track? Thank you sir

Comment: Ye your on the right track. but I think what you want is `dv.testLabel.text = author.title` your setting the destination view controllers attributes. if you do it the other way round your get nil

Comment: I did try it, but no results...what could be the problem?

Comment: hmmm, could you past some more of your code. also you might want to log the variables to check they are not nil

Comment: I see the problem the `prepareForSegue` needs to go in the previous ViewController not the details. it updates the detailsView controller from the previous (table)ViewController as it loads.

Comment: I did try it but the same result :S nothing happens...what to do?

Comment: Add a break point on the `prepareForSegue` is the method being called? Single step through the method and check that all the attributes are correct.

Comment: I just discovered that the method is not called at all! I put a breakpoint and the app continued running normally

Comment: I would suggest that your code does not use `performSegueWithIdentifier` that instead your just straight pushing to the UINavigationController?

Comment: My application is based on navigation Controller that's right, but in the first steps i wasn't capable of pushing data through it, and till now the problem persists...so any ideas?\

Comment: I can't see in your code what performs the move to the detailViewController? can you paste that?

Comment: could you send me an in an email your own email? in that way i will send you the source code...coz actually being new to storyboard is really making me lost ... plz send me your email on elias.rahme.89@gmail.com...and i really appreciate it if you take the time to help me out...Thank you in advance kind Sir]

Comment: I can't give out my email address. I suggest if your still struggling you check out http://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/advanced-iphone-development/id407243028 These should help you