# Going into a second table view when i click on a table view cell of a first table view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

Hi i'm working on a standard Master-Detail Applicaton.

When you create a master-detail application in xcode (i mean the one that it propose when creating a new project), xcode creates a navigation controller, a table view and a detail view, the default behavior when you click the uitableview cell is to go on the detail view.
I would like instead to go on another table view (that of course i had already created in the storyboard). My purpose is to show a list of *filtered values ​​on the basis of what I clicked* (the cell clicked) on the first table view.

So i try to accomplish this from the graphical storyboard, i try to ctrl-drag an arrow from the first-standard table view to the second-new one. Selecting manual segue = show.
And I even deleted the "original" arrow that link the first-standard table view to the detail view (the one proposed by xcode).

But when i click on a table view cell in the simulator, the clicked cell becomes gray and **nothing happens**.

How can I make a second *filtered* table view appear when I click on a first' table view cell?
What should i do to accomplish this?

Ps. i am a very beginner of iOS programming, objective-c and cocoa touch framework. I xcode tag because i would like to know what can be done from within the storyboard (graphically) to accomplish what i need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show a "detail" table view when you click onto a "master" table view cell you can do this with ctrl-drag. Start from the prototype cell (selecting it) of the master view to the second table view, in the storyboard, then choose `show detail` option to create a segue.

click on the segue and check its name in the attributes inspector, it should be showDetail , as in the MasterViewController.swift file you should look at this function, in prepareForSegue you can set the filtered results:
Also:  setDetailItem:object should be changed to another function, since the tableView scene you have created will not have the detailItem property , you can add a property in the h file and set it from prepareForSegue

```
#pragma mark - Segues

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSDate *object = self.objects[indexPath.row];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:object];
    }
}
```

Comment: I've done this, but the problem is not filtering data, the problem is that *it does nothing*. I've put a breakpoint on the if statement and the execution never stops (like it doesn't pass over the breakpoint).

Comment: is it showing the next scene or it is stuck in the masterView and the segue is not working at all?

Comment: It is stuck in the masterView! The only thing is that the clicked cell becomes gray.

Comment: do you have this when you click the segue in storyboard? https://www.dropbox.com/s/33bv1f6cux4431c/Screen%20Shot%202015-07-17%20at%2011.14.13%20AM.png?dl=0

Comment: If you click + on the top right corner of the MasterView when the app is running , AND then click on the newly added cell : it will move to the detailView you have. The problem is that if you don't click + , there are no cells! Let me know if you see this. I suggest you do this by starting with single view application :)

Comment: Yes! However i did it, now it works. Pratically i was doing ctrl-drag from the top of master tableViewController (wrong place). In your image i noticed that the **prototype cell was highlighted**. I tried ctrl-drag from the prototype cell to  the detail and now it works. Thank you for helping me!

Comment: Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is very basic. In short: before you switch to the new TableViewController you fill it with filtered data in `prepareForSegue` according to which cell was clicked.

Apple doc to this subject: [Apple Doc - Navigating a Data Hierarchy with Table Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewAndDataModel/TableViewAndDataModel.html)
 A good answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19806545/1195661

Comment: Thank you for linking the related documentation.