# Custom table view cell with button

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I am using storyboard. I have a table view with 1 Prototype cell, and have four rows in table view. Each cell has a label,image view and a button. Now I want to show different data on next View Controller say(DetailsVc), each time when button is pressed.
Row1- Button click will open DetailsVC with some data.
Row2- Button click will open DetailsVC with different data.
and same process for remaining rows.
Any suggestions.

```
@implementation DetailsVC

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
EmpEngmntTableViewCell *emp;

 if((emp.viewGalleryBtn.tag = 1))
{
    NSLog(@"tag num for 1st row is %ld",(long)emp.viewGalleryBtn.tag);
    self.title = @"Team Building Session";
}
}
```

Comment: Could not understand what you've done. can you please add more code for `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and `DetailVC`?

Comment: Actually I haven't added any code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath. DetailsVC is the next view controller which will open on click of button in previous View controller in custom table view cell. I have made push relation of button with DetailsVC. Now what I want is,                       Row1- Button click will open DetailsVC with some data. Row2- Button click will open DetailsVC with different data. and same process for remaining rows

Comment: selector of your button push button tag with DetailVC ,now in DetailVC check your button tag and make your condation.

Comment: @RamVinayYadav    Can you provide some dummy example or some code?

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers

Comment: then you need to pass data from 1st Viewcontroller to DetailVC. Without passing data you will not able to get data in DetailVC. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8429088/ios-storyboard-passing-data-navigationviewcontroller and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535915/passing-data-between-view-controllers-from-uitableview-to-a-details-view-contr

Comment: -(void)showMyOptionBtn:(UIButton *)sender
{
  
    EventDetailViewController *EventDetail=[[EventDetailViewController alloc]init];
    EventDetail.buttonTag=sender.tag;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:EventDetail animated:NO];
    
}

Comment: now in EventDetailViewController class check  buttonTag and make condation

Answer (score 1):

The best is to use a delegate pattern. I added an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22904164/presentviewcontroller-from-custom-tablecell-in-xib/22904272#22904272), you can use it for example.

Here is an example enclosed:

*Custom Cell .h Class:*

```
@protocol DetailVCProtocol <NSObject>
-(void)loadDetailScreenWithIndex:(NSInteger)rowIndex;
@end

@property (nonatomic, retain) id<DetailVCProtocol> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *btn;
```

*Then Synthesize it in .m file*

*Add this in **m file**:*

```
-(IBAction)loadDetails:(id)sender
{
    // ..... blah blah
    [self.delegate loadDetailScreenWithIndex:btn.tag];
}
```

*The viewcontroller that loads this cell:*

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   // create cell here

   cell.btn.tag = indexPath.row;
   cell.delegate = self;
}

-(void)loadDetailScreenWithIndex:(NSInteger)rowIndex
{
  // Cretae DetailVC with parameter `rowIndex` to populate data
  [self presentViewController:detailVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In function `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

use this code

```
cell.btn.tag = indexPath.row;
[cell.btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnTpd:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

- (IBAction)btnTpd:(id)sender
{
UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
\\You can get which button is pressed by btn.tag
    \\Here call to next ViewController and pass data
}
```

Comment: do NOT use this code for your answer, it is really really bad.

Answer (score -1):

In cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
 cell.optionsBtn.tag=indexPath.row;
 [cell.optionsBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(showMyOptionBtn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

-(void)showMyOptionBtn:(UIButton *)sender
{
  EventDetailViewController *EventDetail=[[EventDetailViewController alloc]init];
  EventDetail.buttonTag=sender.tag;
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:EventDetail animated:NO];

 }

In EventDetailViewController class

   if (self.buttonTag==1) {
     // your condation
   }
   else
   {
    //your condation
   }
```